# Assign Data using Grand Central Dispatch Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, grand-central-dispatch, mapbox

I created a Networking file for downloading data, and I want to assign the data to another view controller so I can populate a map with annotations. The data download successfully, but I can't get it to assign to the view controller. I can only get it working when I include the networking code in the view controller and use DispatchQueue.main.async. I want to keep the networking file and view controller separate. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Apologies in advance for the many lines of code.

The networking file is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class Networking {

static let shared = Networking()

var objects = [Any]()

func getData (_ completionHandler:@escaping (Location?) -> ()) {

    //Create the url with NSURL reuqest
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/locations")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    //Set HTTP method as GET
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    //HTTP Headers
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //Create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in

        guard let data = data,
            let dataStore = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
                print("Could not find network")
                completionHandler(nil)
                return
        }

        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error calling GET")
            completionHandler(nil)
            return
        }

        let HTTPResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("Files downloaded successfully. \(dataStore)" )
        } else {
            completionHandler(nil)
            return
        }

        //Create json object from data
        do {

            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data , options: []) as? [[String: Any]]
let location: [Location] = []

            if let array = json {

                for i in 0 ..< array.count {

                    if let data_object = array[i] as? [String: Any] {

                        if let _id = data_object["_id"] as? String,
                            let name = data_object["name"] as? String,
                            let imageID = data_object["imageID"] as? String,
                            let category = data_object["category"] as? String,
                            let details = data_object["details"] as? String,
                            let latitude = data_object["latitude"] as? Double,
                            let longitude = data_object["longitude"] as? Double {

                            var dictionary  = [_id, name, imageID, category, details, latitude, longitude] as [Any]

                            dictionary.append(location)

                        }
                    }
                } 
             }  
         }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

The model is as follows:

```
class Location {

var _id : String
var name : String
var imageID : String
var category : String
var details : String
var latitude : Double
var longitude : Double

init?(_id: String, name: String, imageID: String, category: String, details: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {

    self._id = _id
    self.name = name
    self.imageID = imageID
    self.category = category
    self.details = details
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude

  }
}
```

The view controller is as follows:

```
 class MapViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self


    Networking.shared.getData { (locations) in


    }

    populateMap()

}

func populateMap (){

    let point = MGLPointAnnotation()
    for location in locations {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude )
        point.coordinate = coordinate
        point.title = location.name
        point.subtitle = location.category
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(point)

    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `NotificationCenter` to do this. for more about `NotificationCenter` refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing completion blocks only in failure cases. Execute the completion block once you have managed to parse the data and pass the array as parameter to closure/block.

```
import UIKit

class Networking {

static let shared = Networking()

var objects = [Any]()

func getData (_ completionHandler:@escaping ([Location]?) -> ()) {

    //Create the url with NSURL reuqest
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/locations")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    //Set HTTP method as GET
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    //HTTP Headers
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //Create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in

        guard let data = data,
            let dataStore = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
                print("Could not find network")
                completionHandler(nil)
                return
        }

        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error calling GET")
            completionHandler(nil)
            return
        }

        let HTTPResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("Files downloaded successfully. \(dataStore)" )
        } else {
            completionHandler(nil)
            return
        }

        //Create json object from data
        do {

            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data , options: []) as? [[String: Any]]
let location: [Location] = []

            if let array = json {

                for i in 0 ..< array.count {

                    if let data_object = array[i] as? [String: Any] {

                        if let _id = data_object["_id"] as? String,
                            let name = data_object["name"] as? String,
                            let imageID = data_object["imageID"] as? String,
                            let category = data_object["category"] as? String,
                            let details = data_object["details"] as? String,
                            let latitude = data_object["latitude"] as? Double,
                            let longitude = data_object["longitude"] as? Double {

                            var dictionary  = [_id, name, imageID, category, details, latitude, longitude] as [Any]

                            dictionary.append(location) //am not sure of what this means test your code

                            completionHandler(location)
                        }
                    }
                } 
             }  
         }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

**Few more mistakes in your code :**

1. Your completion block expects Location as a parameter. but in your code you are creating an array of Locations.

   let location: [Location] = []

So I have modified the completion block parameters to return array of locations

2. In your for loop you are creating

   var dictionary  = [_id, name, imageID, category, details, latitude, longitude] as [Any]

and appending it to  dictionary.append(location) I have no idea what this code is. I believe what u actually trying to do is create a location object from the data and then add it to location array

```
location.append(your_new_location_object)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @j-hooper : Am glad u solved the problem :) Happy coding